# Get iOS device info from a Mac app

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am creating a macOS application that captures a screen recording of a tethered iOS device. I'm using CoreMediaIO. One thing I am not able to figure out is how to simply get certain device info that I need to display.

Setting an AVCaptureDevice gets me sort of there:

```
let device:AVCaptureDevice = listdevices[1]

print("Device Name: \(device.localizedName)")
print("model ID: \(device.modelID)")
print("Manufacturer: \(device.manufacturer)")
print("UDID: \(device.uniqueID)")
```

The above will give me:
- Joe's iPhone
- iOS Device
- Apple, Inc.
- 76e6bc436fdcfd784d6c4e39d11ed2fe9236bb4ec

I still need to know the following:

- iOS version
- Modal # or Name (e.g. Silver iPhone X)

I feel that's all CoreMediaIO has for me...is there a better way?

Edit:
I want this same information that iTunes has when a device is tethered...

[iTunes device info graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYW1m.jpg)

Comment: For something that's *only* a macOS app? I'm doubting it. Maybe something through iTunes (because it's tethered) might help you - well, except when a user decides they don't want to launch iTunes automatically like me. :-) The other thing that could work - but undoubtedly more coding - is to have some kind of client *on* the iOS device where you *might* be able to get what you need (iOS version seems likely to be had). And for sure, you can place this info in your users' hands and simply have them fill it out.

Comment: iTunes app gets this info when a device is tethered, and the info is available to any iOS app via currentDevice(), so I have to believe what I want to do is possible.

Comment: But *only* if it's tethered. More and more, Apple has been moving to have iOS not require this. Who knows what *private* APIs iTunes uses when a device is tethered to get this info?

Comment: Correct. My app requires tethering by design. But you're right...it could very well be a private API.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few ways to do it. These resources have the information I need. Unfortunately, they're not in Swift.

https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library
https://github.com/h3adshotzz/DeviceUtilz

I downloaded and built the second link. Works great and has all the information I'm going to need...but I don't know objective c. :(